# How to exclude bash script case from if statement

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, root

I am running in some problem making a bash script (for showing all disk WWN's in the server, full or short).

I need the script to be run as root and as it is not advised to use root in the script itself, i made an if statement that checks if the script is run as root.

From there the else command runs the script itself as intended. This works fine, but one of my case options (-h) is made for showing help info and can now only be run if the script is run as root, but ideally this should also be able to be used when not run as root.

```
#! /bin/sh
name=`basename "$0"`
usage() {

cat << EOT

Error: arguments required
Usage: ${name} option

    Options:
        -h:     Show this information
        -f:     Show full disk name as used in zpool
        -s:     Show last 8 characters (used as disk labels on the server)

EOT
}

if (( $EUID != 0 )); then
    echo "Please run as root"
    exit
else

while [ -n "$1" ]; do

    case "$1" in
        -f) echo | sudo format | awk '/[[:space:]]+c[0-9]+(d|t)[0-9]+/ {print $2}' | egrep '^.{8,25}';
                                break;;
        -s) for disk in $(echo | sudo format | awk '/[[:space:]]+c[0-9]+(d|t)[0-9]+/ {print $2}' | egrep '^.{8,25}'); do
                                sudo /opt/csw/sbin/smartctl -i -d scsi /dev/rdsk/"$disk" | grep "Logical Unit id:" | sed -r 's/Logical Unit id:      0x//' | grep -Eo '.{8}$'  | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' 
                                done ;
                                break;;
        -h) usage
            break;;

        *) echo "For help: run ${name} -h";;
    esac
    shift
done

fi

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then usage
        exit 0
fi
```

Help is really appreciated!

Comment: eh why not copy the while to somewhere above the exit and remove all but the help option?

Comment: but you can't have a else within the case as far as I know, unless I'm implementing it wrongly...

Comment: @FGOD Actually, you can have `if..else` statements in case statements.

Comment: dont use sudo at all in the script, just check for EUID, then run the script with `sudo script.sh`

Comment: @bac0n yeah I'm still in the process of deleting the sudo commands, but I want the check/help to work properly first

Comment: could do something like this `[[ $1 != -h && (($EUID != 0)) ]]` and think its better to use `while (( $# ))`

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't try bac0n's answer, I found a solution before I read his comments:

I've made a function out of this check and called the function at the needed cases. And I also fixed the fact that the if statement for no arguments was at the button which caused issues too.

The following was my solution to this problem:

```
#! /bin/sh

name=`basename "$0"`
usage() {

cat << EOT

Error: arguments required
Usage: ${name} option

    Options:
        -h:     Show this information
        -f:     Show full disk name as used in zpool
        -s:     Show last 8 characters (used as disk labels on the server)

EOT
}

check_root()
{
    myuid=$(id -u)
    if [ $myuid != '0' ]; then
        echo "This script requires root privilege"
        exit 1
    fi
}

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then usage
        exit 0
fi

while [ -n "$1" ]; do

    case "$1" in
        -f) 
            check_root
            echo | format | awk '/[[:space:]]+c[0-9]+(d|t)[0-9]+/ {print $2}' | egrep '^.{8,25}';
            ;;
        -s) 
            check_root
            for disk in $(echo | format | awk '/[[:space:]]+c[0-9]+(d|t)[0-9]+/ {print $2}' | egrep '^.{8,25}'); do
            /opt/csw/sbin/smartctl -i -d scsi /dev/rdsk/"$disk" | grep "Logical Unit id:" | sed -r 's/Logical Unit id:      0x//' | grep -Eo '.{8}$'  | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'
            done ;
            ;;
        -h) usage
            ;;

        *)  
            echo "For help: run ${name} -h";;
    esac
    shift
done
```

I used id -u instead of the $EUID variable due to having to port this to different distro's and that might not work everywhere

Comment: Avoid backticks for ``name=`basename ...`` -- use `$(...)` instead

Comment: good point, thx @glennjackman

Answer (score 0):

Using [getopt](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/getopt.1.html) to parse command options:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT_NAME=$(basename $BASH_SOURCE)

usage() {

    cat << EOT

Usage: $SCRIPT_NAME option

    Options:
        -h:     Show this information
        -f:     Show full disk name as used in zpool
        -s:     Show last 8 characters (used as disk labels on the server)

EOT

    exit 0
}

# check for legal options.
opt=0
out=$(getopt -o hfs -l help,full,show -u -q -n $BASH_SOURCE -- "$@")
ret=$?
set -- $out
for i in $@; do
    case $i in
        -f|--full)
            ((opt |= 1)) ;;
        -s|--show)
            ((opt |= 2)) ;;
        -h|--help)
            usage ;;
        --)
            break ;;
    esac
done
if ((ret > 0 || opt == 0)); then
    echo "$0: invalid option"
    echo "Try '$0 --help' for more information."
    exit 0
fi

if (( $EUID != 0 )); then
    echo "This command require root privileges."
    exit 0
fi

# code goes here.
if ((opt & 1)); then
    echo "full"
fi

if ((opt & 2)); then
    echo "show"
fi
```

Comment: What is the reason you used getopt instead of normal case like I did? Isn't normal case also checking for valid options? (Never used getopt because I didn't know about it, but it seems unnecessary complicated. But that might be because I miss the knowledge)